# recoding integers in a vector so they register as NA instead?

Tags: r, na, recode

I hope this isn't a silly question but I am REALLY struggling to recode a variable in R so that certain values register as NA instead of the placeholder integer that got read in. respondents who did not answer the question for that column were originally coded as -88, -89 and -99 instead of NA and I only know how to remove them completely from that column.

I want to keep that row, just have those inputs registered as missing. Recode doesn't seem to work b/c NA isn't a value

Thanks!

Comment: Please include some example data `dput(yourdata)` gives you some code, you could paste in here, that we could use to recreate your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try `replace`

```
v <- replace(v,v%in%c(-88,-89,-99),NA)
```

such that

```
> v
[1]  1  2 NA NA -1 NA NA
```

**Dummy Data**

```
v <- c(1,2,-88,-89,-1,-99,-89)
```

Comment: I cannot believe you managed to fix this for me - this worked perfectly!!!!!! THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: @KayleighLavornia You are welcome! If you think my answer addressed your problem, please feel free to accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `%in%` operator to find all positions in a vector which match with another vector, and then set them to NA as follows:

```
dat = data.frame(V1 = c(10, 20, 30, -88, -89, -99))
dat$V1[dat$V1 %in% c(-88, -89, -99)] = NA

dat

 V1
1 10
2 20
3 30
4 NA
5 NA
6 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it, which will replace all values of -88, -89 and -99 in your data:

```
for (i in c(-88, -89, -99)){
  data.df[data.df == i] <- NA
}
```

If you need to just replace in one column (e.g. column 'x'):

```
for (i in c(-88, -89, -99)){
  data.df$x[data.df$x == i] <- NA
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct/ most adequat answer to that question is depending on the exact specifics of your data, in case you have a `numeric` variable and all other values are positive, this would work.

```
somedata <- 
tibble::tribble(
  ~v1, ~v2,
  1,   2,
  3,   4,
  -88, 5,
  6,   -89,
  -99, 1
)

library(tidyverse)

somedata %>% 
  mutate(v1 = ifelse(v1 < 0, NA, v1))

# A tibble: 5 x 2
     v1    v2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2
2     3     4
3    NA     5
4     6   -89
5    NA     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much again to everyone for your help!

I first converted the variable to numeric, then this seemed to work for me:

anesCSV$clinton.withNA <- replace(anesCSV$clintonthermo_numeric,anesCSV$clintonthermo_numeric%in%c(-88,-89,-99),NA)

As someone initially suggested:

v <- replace(v,v%in%c(-88,-89,-99),NA)

I did create a new variable to store the results personally!